# CCCallFunc usage in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am getting warning on this line stating that method actionWithTarget is deprecated.
Can any one tell which alternative method can be used in cocos2dx

```
CCCallFunc *callBackfunc = CCCallFunc::actionWithTarget(this,
                           callfunc_selector(GamePlay::startTrumphetAnimation));
```

Thanks

Comment: pass parameter in your function definition like startTrumphetAnimation(CCObject* sender)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
CCCallFunc *func = CCCallFunc::create(this, callfunc_selector(GameOverScene::MyFunction));
```

//Declare this function also

```
void GameOverScene::MyFunction(CCObject* sender) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using new version of Cocos2dx ,

```
auto funcCallAction = CallFunc::create([=](){
    // TODO: do you stuff here
    startTrumphetAnimation();
});

runAction(funcCallAction);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CCCallFunc *calFunc = CCCalFunc::create(this,callfunc_selector(ClassName::methodName));
```

If you are using cocos2dx v3:

```
CallFunc *calFunc = CalFunc::create(CC_CALLBACK_1(ClassName::methodName,this));


void ClassName::methodName(Ref* sender)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write function definition in this way

void GamePlay::startTrumphetAnimation(CCObject* sender) 
{

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using COCOS2DX-3.0 or 3.14v

```
runAction( CallFunc::create([=]() { startTrumphetAnimation() }));
```

But you should write this line inside any method of GamePlay Class.

Comment: What does "(=)" means ?

Comment: [=] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by copy and current object by reference if exists